# Keyboards with built in SmartCard reader. PIN/Password to unlock not via Computer

Tags: hardware, smartcard

I am looking for keyboards with a built in SmartCard reader, where the Smartcard can be unlocked directly without going via the computer. The keyboards I found so far connect the SmartCard reader via an integrated USB hub which opens the door for key loggers to snatch the PIN/password. Are there any keyboards where the SmartCard can be unlocked locally that don't transmit the PIN/password to the connected computer?

To clarify for what it will be used:

The employes will get SmartCards with authentication certificates on them. The SmartCard is protected by a PIN/Password. The user will:

1. insert the card
2. enter the card PIN/password (preferably locally)
3. enter the password for the certificate (on the computer)

We made tests with 
external readers similar to the one [here](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=acr83) and the local handling of the unlock by PIN worked fine. Now we are looking for a way to remove the "extra device" on the table.

Comment: This would be difficult to implement to be more secure than doing it on a computer itself.  How does the keyboard transmit the all clear to the computer?  What prevents this signal from being cloned?  I suppose it might be possible to use the keyboard to directly unlock the card and then have the card handle the connection, but it sounds like it would be pretty difficult to setup and might introduce risks about attacks convincing a smart card to authenticate something you didn't want to authenticate (since it is unlocked by different hardware than it is authenticating to).

Comment: How would it be more difficult to implement than the Secure PIN Entry (SPE) in the following device: http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=acr83 ?

Comment: the point of that device is Payment capture.  It is either a) communicating the payment information directly to the payment gateway (thus bypassing the computer completely), b) being given a transaction to sign and signing it or c) passing the payment information after unlock.  I suppose that authentication could be accomplished by doing a challenge/response signing, but it would open the door for something other than the login to provide the challenge.

Comment: Well maybe i should explain what we want to use it for. We want to use two factor authentication to log on to our system. The employes will get SmartCards with authentication certificates on them. The SmartCard is protected by a PIN/Password. The user will 1. insert the card 2. enter the card PIN/password (preferably locally) 3. enter the password for the certificate (on the computer). We made tests with external readers similar to the one I mentioned above and the local handling of the unlock by PIN worked fine. Now we are looking for a way to remove the "extra device" on the table.

Comment: ah, ok, so that is more or less fitting with my b) scenario.  I guess that works ok since it still ensures the card is present and can't be reproduced without the card and the pin to unlock the card isn't around.  Alright, I just had to finish thinking it through.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with what you ask for is about sharing the keyboard with the OS. When a keyboard is plugged in a machine, then the operating system on that machine is made aware of every key press and key release event, and the OS maintains the knowledge of which key is pressed at any time. For your PIN entry scenario, you not only need the key presses to be sent to the smart card, but you also want the same key presses *not* to be sent to the operating system.

The keyboard, by itself, won't be able to guess whether you are about to type a PIN code. You could imagine a specific command sent from the computer, which tells to the keyboard: "now, key presses should be sent to the smart card, not to me". But you do not trust the host computer (that's the point of the discussion), so you cannot trust it for actually sending this command. Therefore, your special keyboard, if it exists at all, should have a manual switch or at least an indicator LED which the OS cannot override (e.g. the LED turns green when key presses are sent to the smart card).

You would not be at the end of your worries, though. Because when you use the smart card to perform a payment, the card "authenticates" the payment order (with some operation that the bank will accept as valid; this could be a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)
or a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)). You then want to be sure that what the card sees and signs is indeed the payment order you believe. Since you do not trust the host computer, you need an extra display.

When you go down the road of "host computer is potentially hostile", you normally end up with the idea that the smart card reader should have its own keyboard *and* display, so that it may show you what you are about to sign, and makes sure that your PIN code goes to the card only. Ideally, the reader should run the banking application itself (to assemble the order in the right format). At that point, you have a [payment terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_terminal), which is a small, *tamper-resistant* computer with its own CPU, RAM, Flash, display, keyboard and smart card reader. The important point is that, short of a full-featured payment terminal, you will not get substantial security against an hostile host computer.

**The easier way** is to trust the host computer, so that you may reuse the components that the host computer already offers: CPU, RAM, storage, display, keyboard...

Comment: The answer does not demonstrate knowledge on whether or not such keyboards exist (the question). Also, the question isn't about payments (it mentions user authentication).

Comment: You're right that secure PIN entry is not a cure-all. However, what it does is slightly mitigate the risk presented by a compromised computer. Without being able to know the PIN, the attacker will be able to do harm only as long as the smart card is connected to the computer and the user is entering PINs. The attacker won't be able to use the card if he goes and steals it.