# What is the most secure hardware option for the use of personal eIDAS compliant QES in the EU?

Tags: digital-signature

I know that there are two approaches, one with local capsulated storage, such as USB token or smartcard, and the other with cloud-based key vault. Both are secured with a PIN that has to be entered in the client requesting authentication. Exposing the PIN to the software system however worries me.

My concern is that the client devices, personal computer or smartphone, host customizable software environments with network facing components. As such, they are likely subjects to exploits and in the case that they are compromised by some kind of malware, I am concerned that it would enable theft of the PIN and temporarily allow unauthorized transactions with it by that same malware. Assuming that the USB token is a challenge-response oracle device, not simply encrypted storage, if it had some kind of acknowledgement, a hardware button, which limits the authentications that it performs and also had a keypad that allowed entering the PIN securely, it would have minimized the consequences from using infected client systems.
Are such setups available or what is the closest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are such setups available or what is the closest solution?

Yes, there are some smartcard readers providing 'Secure Pin Entry', see for instance those at [https://www.smartcardfocus.us/shop/ilp/se~6/pinpad-smartcard-readers/p/index.shtml](https://www.smartcardfocus.us/shop/ilp/se%7E6/pinpad-smartcard-readers/p/index.shtml)

I think that would be eIDAS compliant.

Additionally, multiple security keys, including some YubiKeys, support requiring an external action to validate the action (although this may not be compatible with your eIDAS requisite).

However, no matter how you validate the user, you should note the points on [this response](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33279/49489): even if the pin itself is safe, the transaction that is being signed could be malicious.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was vaguely aware of the existence of physical security keys before I asked. There are even models with keypads by some vendors, but while they mention support for many protocols, I found no explicit mention of eIDAS.

Comment: I ignored the issue of transaction verification, because of the limitations of the token/smartcard reader interface, but I think I underestimated the issue. I imagined simply acknowledging a single transaction with a button, expecting that the device would reject a request if it detects contention from multiple applications. Something like what YubiKeys offers, maybe. I confess, it is not as tamper-resistant as a POS terminal, but another measure. I don't trust my PC. A customizable software environment is susceptible to attacks.

Comment: Maybe you should try contacting their sales department. I would be surprised if they cannot work under that, specially those doing business in Europe. There's not much reason for a smartcard reader not to comply, but...

Comment: I was a bit vague there. The hardware/physical security key offerings, e.g., YubiKeys or OnlyKey, do not seem to mention eIDAS particularly, but rather protocols like U2F, FIDO2, UAF. I was initially interested, since OnlyKey actually has a variant with a strange "senary" keypad option (6-digit one). Altogether, that was an aside. Since you directed me to the option, I found smartcard readers with PIN keypads offered by electronics retailers in my area. I am going to consult the OTPs for supported devices, as you suggested. Thanks again.